# How to disable popups in Firefox without add-ons?

Tags: firefox, popups, advertisements

For the past 5-10 years or so, I've been using Firefox, and I've never found out how to properly disable popups. I am now using Firefox 24.2.0 on Linux without Flash or Java. I used to just disable JavaScript, which seemed to work (at least for sites that don't need JavaScript), but new versions of Firefox remove that feature. I find the dominating time I waste during any day is on closing popup windows. I typically get 10-500 popups per day. I've heavily used some 40 computers over the last years, all with various versions of Linux and Windows, and in various locations (home/work/school) and I've always had the same problem. So it doesn't seem to be a malware issue.

All these years, I always checked the "Block pop-up windows" button:
[image]

But it seems this doesn't do what I want it to. For example [this](https://thepiratebay.se/torrent/9059456) page just showed a popup window when I clicked on the description. Also [this](http://www.mediafire.com/download/60w8cjpvellykgf/Belusxmanuelel007.rar) page shows a popup when I click on the description or file name. I sometimes even get pages that show 4-10 popup windows.

Maybe I'm using the wrong option to disable popups? What does this option that I turned on actually do?

Comment: Would blocking **all** popups by default work for you? And then manually adding exceptions for safe/required websites?

Comment: @and31415: Indeed, that would work, my question is exactly asking how to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Firefox settings

Many settings, especially the most advanced ones, are not present in the User Interface (UI) options dialog.

> Preference settings that are modified from default values are saved in the [`prefs.js`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prefs.js_file) file. Instead of directly editing this file, recent Mozilla applications include a configuration editor that can be accessed from the application interface.
>
> <sub>Source: [Editing configuration](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration)</sub>
>
> In Firefox, type `about:config` in the Location Bar (address bar) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to display the list of preferences [...]. If you see a page with the warning message, "This might void your warranty!", click the button labeled "I'll be careful, I promise!", to continue (in fact, there is no warranty whatsoever, it's more a joke to ensure that users are aware of what they are about to do). Use the checkbox there to avoid the warning in the future.
>
> To add a new preference, context-click (right-click) anywhere in the list of preferences. In the context menu, select **New** then select the type of preference you are adding.
>
> To modify an existing preference, context-click (right-click) on the preference, select **Modify** and type in the new value.
>
> To reset a preference to its default value or to remove an added preference, context-click (right-click) on the preference and select **Reset**.
>
> You can use the **Search** bar at the top of the `about:config` page to filter the preferences that you want to inspect. The search bar is case-insensitive, unlike the actual configuration variables.
>
> <sub>Source: [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config)</sub>

### Pop-up related preferences

Here's a comprehensive list I've come up with:

- `browser.link.open_newwindow`

  **Type** Integer
  **Default value** `3`

  **Description** Controls where to open links that would normally open in a new window. Possible values:

  - `1` (or anything else) - open in the current tab or window.
  - `2` - open in a new window.
  - `3` - open in a new tab.

  Enabling or disabling the **Open new windows in a new tab instead** UI option will toggle this preference between `3` and `2`.
- `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction`

  **Type** Integer
  **Default value** `2`

  **Description** Restricts all new windows opened by JavaScript. Possible values:

  - `0` - always force new windows into tabs.
  - `1` - don't restrict new windows.
  - `2` - force windows that don't specify their features (e.g. width, height) into tabs.
- `browser.popups.showPopupBlocker`

  **Type** Boolean
  **Default value** `true`

  **Description** Determines whether to show an icon in the status bar when a pop-up has been blocked. Obsolete, just leave it as-is.
- `dom.disable_open_click_delay`

  **Type** Integer
  **Default value** `1000`

  **Description** Handles pop-ups according to the current pop-up blocker settings when created through a [JavaScript timing event](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) using a delay smaller than this value (in milliseconds).
- `dom.disable_open_during_load`

  **Type** Boolean
  **Default value** `true`

  **Description** When enabled, blocks pop-ups created while the page is loading. This setting is equivalent to the **Block pop-up windows** UI option.
- `dom.disable_window_flip`

  **Type** Boolean
  **Default value** `true`

  **Description** Determines whether windows can be focused through JavaScript.
- `dom.disable_window_move_resize`

  **Type** Boolean
  **Default value** `false`

  **Description** Determines whether windows can be moved or resized using JavaScript.
- `dom.disable_window_open_feature.*`

  **Description** Rather than a single preference, this is a set of different boolean settings which can prevent a specific pop-up feature (e.g. address bar, scroll bars, etc.) from being disabled when set to `true`. Available preferences:

  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.close`
  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.location`
  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.menubar`
  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.minimizable`
  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.personalbar`
  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable`
  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.scrollbars`
  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.status`
  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.titlebar`
  - `dom.disable_window_open_feature.toolbar`
- `dom.disable_window_status_change`

  **Type** Boolean
  **Default value** `true`

  **Description** When enabled, prevents the status bar text from being changed via JavaScript.
- `dom.popup_allowed_events`

  **Type** String
  **Default value** `change click dblclick mouseup reset submit touchend`

  **Description** A space-separated list of the events allowed to create pop-ups. Although undocumented, setting the value to a single space character will create an empty list, thus disabling all pop-ups (exceptions still apply). The same effect can be achieved by specifying a non-existent event (e.g. `none`).
- `dom.popup_maximum`

  **Type** Integer
  **Default value** `20`

  **Description** Limits the number of simultaneously open pop-up windows.
- `privacy.popups.disable_from_plugins`

  **Type** Integer
  **Default value** `2`

  **Description** Controls pop-ups created by plug-ins (e.g. Adobe Flash Player). Possible values:

  - `0` - no restrictions.
  - `1` - limits the pop-ups number to `dom.popup_maximum`.
  - `2` - block all pop-ups except for whitelisted websites.
  - `3` - block all pop-ups.
- `privacy.popups.policy`

  **Type** Integer
  **Default value** `1`

  **Description** Deprecated. Use `dom.disable_open_during_load` instead.
- `privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage`

  **Type** Boolean
  **Default value** `true`

  **Description** Determines whether to display an information bar whenever one ore more pop-us are blocked. Can be changed by using the **Don't show info bar when pop-ups are blocked** UI option.
- `privacy.popups.usecustom`

  **Type** Boolean
  **Default value** `true`

  **Description** Apparently unused.

### Recommended settings

These are the values I currently use for the settings listed above; feel free to experiment with other settings on your own. Tested with Firefox 27.0.1.

```
browser.link.open_newwindow;3
browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction;0
browser.popups.showPopupBlocker;true
dom.disable_open_click_delay;1000
dom.disable_open_during_load;true
dom.disable_window_flip;true
dom.disable_window_move_resize;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.close;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.location;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.menubar;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.minimizable;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.personalbar;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.scrollbars;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.status;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.titlebar;true
dom.disable_window_open_feature.toolbar;true
dom.disable_window_status_change;true
dom.popup_allowed_events; 
dom.popup_maximum;20
privacy.popups.disable_from_plugins;2
privacy.popups.policy;1
privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage;false
privacy.popups.usecustom;true
```

## Further reading

- [Pop-up blocker settings, exceptions and troubleshooting](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting)
- [A brief guide to Mozilla preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences)
- [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config)
- [about:config entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)

Comment: Setting `dom.popup_allowed_events` to a space worked. Other things I tried that didn't work: `browser.link.open_newwindow=1` made the mediafire page open about:blank in a new window and the current page change to about:blank as well; The pirate bay would open a popup and it would immediately close. `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction=0` worked (made the popups show in a new tab). `dom.disable_open_click_delay=90000`, `dom.popup_maximum=0`, and `dom.popup_maximum=1` didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I created and linked a Superuser account just so that I could upvote the original question and your excellent answer. I've used it to configure at least five installations of Firefox so far.  Based on your answer, the process which works for me is really short. Go to: about:config. Set browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction=0 and dom.popup_allowed_events=''.  It works beautifully!