# How can I set Firefox to block every pop-ups, using only native browser options, without installing any add-on?

Tags: firefox, browser, popups

[Some](https://superuser.com/questions/1115482/how-to-block-ad-popups-in-web-browser) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/834203/how-to-block-advertisement-popups-in-web-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1) have been asked before about blocking pop-ups, but they don't fit my needs of using the default browser options.

Basically, Firefox has an integrated "block pop-up" option that you can check to prevent unwanted pop-up from appearing (e.g. if you're not the one who initiated the action to open it, such as a click for example).

However, nowadays, some unwanted pop-ups are bypassing that by appearing the instant you click on anything on the web page, which make the browser believe that you willingly tried to open it.

Back when I used Internet Explorer 11, I could configure the browser to block any pop-up from appearing at all, whether I willingly tried to open it or not. If I truly wanted to open it, I could bypass the pop-up blocker by either telling the browser to temporarily allow them, or click with the mouse wheel.

Although Firefox doesn't have any user friendly option like that, [you can edit some configuration variables to prevent pop-ups from opening.](https://superuser.com/a/1315038/971562)

But that's still not good enough. When I check out whether or not it's good enough on [a pop-up test website](http://web.archive.org/web/20201017153749/http://www.popuptest.com/goodpopups.html), one of the pop-up still manages to get through (the 2nd pop-up link still manages to either open a new window or a new tab, depending on whether you configured your browser to open link into a new tab instead of a new window).

How can I tell Firefox to block any pop-up, window, from opening at all, by using only the browser's native option, without having to install any add-on nor extension?

Comment: "Blocking pop-ups doesn't always work: Although Firefox blocks most pop-ups, some websites may show pop-ups using uncovered methods, even when they are blocked." from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting

Comment: Possible dupe: https://superuser.com/questions/697018/how-to-disable-popups-in-firefox-without-add-ons

Comment: @DavidPostill I just checked it out. Some of the stuffs the linked question's answer suggested were things I already tried out. It looks like the 2nd popup of the popup test I linked is still getting through, otherwise it would have been good.

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. Popups 2 and 3 get through for me ... All the others on that site are blocked.

Comment: My apologies for editing this old question. I realised the popup test link didn't work anymore because it was replaced by a doubtful casino website. So I replaced it with a wayback machine link.